# Document types as more than 'object'?

Tags: typescript, documentation, typedoc

When I create documentation with `typedoc` interfaces are documented with properties, but types are only documented as `object`, for example:

```
CreateProjectResponse
CreateProjectResponse: object
Defined in src/requests/createProjectRequest.ts:16
```

I would prefer the documentation to show the properties of the object.

Is this possible to do?

PS: I am using types for 'responses' in my code for consistency because some responses are primitives, and this can't be named using interfaces.

Comment: Could you show the source for that type?

Comment: This problem went away when I removed some exclude files from the typedoc config file.